# Use CMD inside Python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, cmd

Good evening everyone, this is the first time I post here.

I have many codes I need to run in CMD but I'm not good at coding with CMD, so I want to use python to modify the code that I have to repeat often

for example

```
temp1 = ["C:/dir1", "C:/dir2", "C:/dir3"]
temp2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
for i, p in zip(temp1, temp2):
    os.system('7z -a "{}" C:/target/output"{}" -m5'.format(i, p))
```

With my code, I also need to see the Shell prompt, because some of the codes I do show a very long terminal data output that I want to monitor actively, I prefer to see it in the python terminal as an output, or print or something similar.

Thanks in advance, it is my first post hope it's clear.

Comment: So, the command %comspec% should be used in a CMD window? I am trying that on python and it returns a "0" but that's it. I always use jupyter notebook, not sure if its the best way to do it.

Could you create a python script with my code? or a similar example.

Comment: What is the point in running `cmd.exe` (implicitly via `os.system()`) just to run another executable (`7z.exe`), why not simply run the latter directly (by `subprocess.call()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system()` implicitly uses `cmd.exe` on Windows (by passing the specified command line to `cmd /c`) and implicitly passes the command's output through to stdout.

Therefore, your command should work in principle, though I recommend double-quoting the target path *in full* (`"C:/target/output{}"`), not just the substituted part (`C:/target/output"{}"`)<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
import os

temp1 = ["C:/dir1", "C:/dir2", "C:/dir3"]
temp2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
for i, p in zip(temp1, temp2):
    os.system('7z -a "{}" "C:/target/output{}" -m5'.format(i, p))
```

**If you're running this code from a *GUI* script** (a script invoked via `pythonw.exe` / `pyw.exe`), the console window created for each `os.system()` call automatically closes when the command finishes, which doesn't allow you to inspect the output after the fact. To address this, you have two options:

- Append **`& pause`** to the command, which **waits for keypress before closing the console window**:

```
import os

temp1 = ["C:/dir1", "C:/dir2", "C:/dir3"]
temp2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
for i, p in zip(temp1, temp2):
    os.system('7z -a "{}" "C:/target/output{}" -m5 & pause'.format(i, p))
```

- Invoke your command via **`cmd /k`**, which **starts an interactive `cmd.exe` session that stays open after the command finishes**; note that **each such session then *blocks* further execution of your Python script until you manually close the console window** in which the persistent `cmd.exe` session runs.

```
import os

temp1 = ["C:/dir1", "C:/dir2", "C:/dir3"]
temp2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
for i, p in zip(temp1, temp2):
    os.system('cmd /k " 7z -a "{}" "C:/target/output{}" -m5 "'.format(i, p))
```

<sup>Note the unusual quoting (an outer `"..."` string in which *embedded* `"` aren't *escaped*), which is what `cmd.exe` supports, however.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Typically, this shouldn't make a difference, but you never know how programs parse their command line on Windows, and double-quoting an argument in full is more likely to work.</sup>